# JavaScript to set value of variable inside it, and then after retrive variable's data on another call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want a function in JS, which can take some value at first call and set it to a variable inside it.
And then again on another call i want to again get the data of that variable.

something like this: 
**while calling the function for first time**

```
function set_and_get(value){
    var a = value;
}
```

**on another call it should return the value like**

```
returned_value = set_and_get()
```

Thanks.

Comment: Once the function finishes running, it goes outside of scope, as do any local variables within it. Meaning that these values are lost. You would need to set your `value` to some global field that is stored outside of your `set_and_get` function. Such as `this`.

Comment: i know global can work, But i want to restrict the use of it. as it is visible for user.

Comment: Sounds like you _might_ need to use partial application

Comment: http://benalman.com/news/2012/09/partial-application-in-javascript/

Comment: Yep, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56189815/5409412 (answer below)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally the pattern looks more like this where the function will return another function which you then would use.

```js
function set_and_get(value){
    return function () {
      return value;
    }
}

var test = set_and_get(1)
console.log(test())

var test2 = set_and_get(2)
console.log(test(), test2())
```

Now if the function can not be reused, aka once it is set, it is done. You could just overwrite the function. It is not the best practice, but it can work.

```js
function set_and_get(value) {
  set_and_get = function() {
    return value;
  }
  return value
}

console.log(set_and_get(1))
console.log(set_and_get())
console.log(set_and_get(2))
```

Comment: You answer is just perfect as i wanted, but I want to ask that is: is the value of the function will be accessible from console by any means?

Comment: So I think there's no way to stop this type of variable from being accessed from console.

Comment: I can rewrite any function in the console..... `const` in ES6 will help, but I can set a break point and alter it anyway I want.

Comment: i did not understand

Comment: in this solution the value will always always be 1. even after set_and_get(2) the value is still 1.

Comment: @marshy101 Because that is what OP wants.... Once it is set, it does not change. The first code block will change if that is an option the OP wanted, the second one will not if that is what OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

While not necessarily recommended, you can attach a property to the function object itself:

```
function get_and_set(value) {
    if (value !== undefined) {
        get_and_set._value = value;
    } else {
        return get_and_set._value;
    }
}
```

but note that the property is in no way protected - it is possible to read it (And overwrite it) from outside the helper function.

Comment: can you please tell me why it is not recommended

Comment: @FightWithCode because it ties that variable to that one specific instance of the function (albeit that might be exactly what you want to achieve).    If you only want the setter to be callable once on first use then the pattern in the other answer (which allows you to create multiple "set once" variables) may be more appropriate.

Comment: But the value can still be accessed as a global variable like get_and_set._value, which i don't want to do so.

Comment: right, because the only way to truly prevent that is to have the function make a _closure_ over the value (i.e. retain its value in its scope) which requires that the getter can't be the same function, but instead a function that's in that same scope.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use a combination of concepts called closure and high order function.

```
var set_and_get_fn = function(value){
 var a = value; 
 var set_and_get = function(){
    return a;
 }
 return set_and_get;
}

var set_and_get = set_and_get_fn(10);
var returned_value = set_and_get();
// 10
set_and_get();
// still 10
set_and_get = set_and_get_fn(12);
set_and_get();
//12
set_and_get();
//12
```

Closure allows an inner function `set_and_get` to have access to the variables of it's outer function/context `set_and_get_fn`, even after `set_and_get_fn` has returned. `set_and_get` has closed over variable `a`. High order functions allows you to treat functions as objects, you can pass them as arguments and return them from functions. I'm returning `set_and_get` function from `set_and_get_fn`

Comment: It also does not stops the variable from being accessed inside console.

Comment: NOTHING will stop it from being accessed in the console.

Comment: @FightWithCode you can not access `var a` in the console